# Google chrome is truncating my web site, why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Has anyone seen the following rendering bug in google chrome:

[bug http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/126/annoying_rendering_bug.jpg](http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/126/annoying_rendering_bug.jpg)

I get it occasionally when I navigate to http://www.mediabrowser.tv

What causes it? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I've seen it too. I don't know how to fix it, but I can confirm that it is something that happens sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this right now, but I've seen similar in the past. Generally this happens when the element with the background is not full height.

Be sure you are applying the background to the `body` (which defaults to height 100%) and that you are not applying styles to the `html` tag (which would throw off the body rendering).

Try inspecting that white bit when next it happens. You might gain more insight into what's going wrong.

Another possibility is that the page hasn't finished loading the GA code at the bottom. If your script blocks at the end of your page take too long to execute you might see this before the closing `html` tag is rendered.

Possibly related: [Chromium issue 5388](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5388&can=1&q=white%20bar%20bottom&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)

Comment: As in, chuck the container in a sub container and give it background color of #ABABAB as opposed to applying that to the html tag

Comment: Apply the background color to the `body` tag and don't apply any styles to the `html` tag. Doing so isn't technically valid, and it can cause the `body` to behave more like a `div`.

Comment: However, I just tested this theory and can't seem to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry mistyped there, the bg is already applied only to the body tag. nothing is applied to the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

**omitted close tag...**

It is possible that a closing tag was omitted.

Comment: unlikely as the html validates http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mediabrowser.tv/

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Google Chrome as well, on Windows XP and I am not having a problem with the Rendering. Try closing your tab and reopening sometimes it has a caching type of error like most browsers do occasionally.

Comment: the issue only happens once in a while ... which is what really confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem lies in specifying a height for the container while floating elements inside. Parent elements are never to expand to contain floated children. The only thing preventing this from collapsing altogether is the p element inside the last div. I'm not sure Chrome is doing anything wrong though Firefox is different but I don't have time to look at it further right now.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason, `<div style="overflow: auto; height: 400px;">` if you forget adding **overflow: auto** to your style or somewhere in your stylesheet that truncation happens. IE can accomodate that, but not Chrom and FireFox. Some default height is necessary but not sufficient. W3C validator pass the code without that elaboration since it does not consider the semantic (logical) errors.